# Unrecoverable Error: Failed to load message journal

Tags: jboss, hornetq

I am using Jboss 6.x. I noticed the below message in the JbossServer.log

```
    2014-08-02 03:55:28.870 SEVERE [HornetQServerImpl] Unrecoverable Error: Failed to load message       journal from  /hornetq/journal. To recover stop the server, move the contents of this directory to a temporary location and restart the server. Please submit the corrupt files and a copy of the logs to support for analysis.
    2014-08-02 03:55:28.871 SEVERE [HornetQServerImpl] Failure in initialisation: java.lang.NullPointerException    at org.hornetq.core.persistence.impl.journal.JournalStorageManager.loadPreparedTransactions(JournalStorageManager.java:1910) [:]
```

What does this means? under what conditions the problem occurs? any suggestions?

Comment: check if you have `journal` folder in your src. If not then create one.

Comment: Yes, the folder /hornetq/journal does exists. After moving contents to some temporary location, we are able to start the HornetQ.My question is what is the problem? how to prevent it in future?

Comment: I don't think you can do anything with this. Generally It should not come frequently. If it is coming again contact JBoss support team with all files in this folder.